# How do i detect count of 'x' in cells and count of longest continued series of 'x'?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating Google Sheets spreadsheet inspired from [here.](https://medium.com/@hcokim/tracking-habits-with-google-sheets-3f769871da77#.rbxn05h0n) It is habit tracking spreadsheet. [image: spreadsheet].User need to write x if current day is successful. The function detects longest continuous series of 'x', and displays steak(ount of longest continued series of 'x'). I would like to use this functionality locally on my machine. I am not able to modify the offset function in the sheet.

```
No   Habit     Steak     Max   02/02/2016    02/03/2016    02/04/2016
1    Habit1    1         3     x             x             x
2    Habit2    2         2     x             x             x
3    Habit3    5         10    x             x             x
```

Here No is numbering field.

Habit is name of habit being tracked.

Steak is the total continuous days on which x is found. If there is one space, steak is broken.

Max is maximum numbers of days the x was continued.

Rest columns are days with date as heading.

I need the function to calculate steak and max.

Comment: Perhaps instead of a picture you could create a small table and, importantly, include your expected results.

Comment: @XORLX full google spreadsheet version is available here.I would like to make the same for ms excel.

https://medium.com/@hcokim/tracking-habits-with-google-sheets-3f769871da77#.rbxn05h0n

Comment: Sorry but I am not willing to recreate an entire spreadsheet for you. If you post the table I requested then I can give you a formula which will generate your results.

Comment: @XORLX i do not want my spreadsheet created. I just posted link so it can be viewed nicely and my question can be understood.

Comment: @XORLX i have added table.

Comment: Thanks, but all three rows in there have precisely three "x"s each, so why do the results differ?

Answer (score 2):

The following formula will give you the max continuous series of 'x' for a activity. Copy it down for the number of activities you have.

```
   =iferror(if(countif($D2:2,"x")=0,0,max(arrayformula(len(split(concatenate(transpose(arrayformula(if($D2:2="x","x","|")))),"|"))))))
```

Comment: I am receiving error, "You`ve entered too few arguments for this function."  check this for screenshot. https://imgur.com/X4FaE8V

Comment: 1. If the row is empty, the result is 16 instead of 0. 2. eventually will be a lot of columns, so instead of $B2:$Q2 $B2:2 should be used. 3. The inner filter is unnecessary.

Comment: @ByomkeshBakhsy I edited the formula in the answer to fit your sample spreadsheet. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewed version of the formula proposed in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35184876/1595451) by Ed Nelson

> The following formula will give you the max continuous series of 'x'
>   for a activity. Copy it down for the number of activities you have.

```
=if(
   countif($D2:2,"x")=0,
   0,
   max(
      arrayformula(
         len(
            split(
               concatenate(
                  transpose(
                     arrayformula(
                        if($D2:2="x","x","|")
                     )
                  )
               ),
               "|"
            )
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Notes:

1. The above formula should be added to row 2. If it will be added to another row update the row reference accordingly.
2. It's assumed that only the cells to be used to track habits will have a "big fat X".

Comment: is correct. The filter is not needed. I have adopted the changes. I could not get the cell references to work on Byomkesh Bakhsy's sample spreadsheet. The updated formula will work. Thanks Ruben for the improvements!

Answer (score 0):

Guys from the forum [forum.Chandoo.org](http://forum.chandoo.org/) made formulas and created sample sheet. This works exactly like i wanted. [this is the thread link.](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/habit-tracking-spreadsheet.27679/)

The formulas are:

> for Cell C2 = LOOKUP(99,FREQUENCY(IF(E2:T2<>"",COLUMN(E2:T2)),(E2:T2="")*COLUMN(E2:T2)))
>
> For Cell D2 = MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(E2:T2<>"",COLUMN(E2:T2)),(E2:T2="")*COLUMN(E2:T2)))

This works. There is reference link for the formulas,[here.](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-frequency-function)